What's the difference between gcloud artifacts docker tags list and gcloud artifacts docker images list as the later doesn't provide me tag value
I want to pull the latest image from GAR.
I fould a thread which helped me with the command (How to get latest version of an image from artifact registry), however my tags value is empty when i verify with --format=json argument.
The way i can see tags is using gcloud artifacts docker tags list $IMAGE_REGISTRY/$IMAGE_REPO/$FE_IMAGE_NAME --format="value(TAG)". However the format doesn't allow for filtering based on update/creation time since the output only includes image,tag,version.
Are there some permissions missing or are those two commands completely different?
To get the latest image i'll have to write a loop to scan through and filter, which sure is complicated to look at randomly in a script

It's not the same thing. In one case you list the images in your registry, in the other you list the tags on an image. You can get both in the same time, pretty normal.

Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere , but why image list output doesn't provide tag value when the docker tags list provides with the same

It's the API behavior!! Ask Google why they design it like it. I think it's a question of object, relation and cardinality, but it's only my thoughts, I'm not a Google Engineer!
